# How to pass the value to particular row in aura:iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Component:

```
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.QliList}" var="Qli" indexVar="sNo">      
               <tr>
                    <td><div class="slds-truncate">{!sNo+1}</div></td>
                    <td><div class="slds-truncate">{!Qli.Name}</div></td>
                    <td><div class="slds-truncate">{!Qli.Description__c}</div></td>
                   <td><div class="slds-truncate">{!Qli.Family__c}</div></td>
                   <td><div class="slds-truncate"><ui:inputText aura:id="dynamicResult" class="pnsuggestion" value="{!Qli.Part_number_Suggestion__c}"/></div></td>
                   <!--<td><div class="slds-truncate">{!Qli.PN_Suggestion__c}</div></td>-->
                    <td><div class="slds-truncate"></div>
                    <lightning:button type="button" onclick="{!c.UpdatePnsuggestion}"   name="CMM Tooling and Accessories" label="{!sNo}">CMM Tooling and Accessories</lightning:button>
<lightning:button type="button" onclick="{!c.UpdatePnsuggestion}"  name="CMM Prewired" label="{!sNo}">CMM Prewired</lightning:button>
 </td>
                </tr>
          </aura:iteration>
```

Js controller:

```
 UpdatePnsuggestion: function(component,event,helper){
   var va= event.getSource().get("v.name");
   var indexnumber= event.getSource().get("v.label");
  console.log(indexnumber);
    component.set("v.QliList.Part_number_Suggestion__c", va);  
},
```

I want to pass the button value to inputtext field {!Qli.Part_number_Suggestion__c}

In iteration n number of record when I click on a button it is copying the value to all records. But in my case, I would like to copy value only to the current row. Please Help me on this.

I am getting row number as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all the value because:-

You button markup is :- `<lightning:button type="button" onclick="{!c.UpdatePnsuggestion}"  name="CMM Prewired" label="{!sNo}">CMM Prewired</lightning:button>` where name attribute has hardcoded value. i.e. CMM Prewired . The name is same for all the rows and hence giving you all the rows.

You need to assign a dynamic value from iteration variable like:- **{!Qli.Name}**

So you button markup will be:-

```
<lightning:button type="button" onclick="{!c.UpdatePnsuggestion}"  name="{!Qli.Name}" label="{!sNo}">CMM Prewired</lightning:button>
```

Then `var va= event.getSource().get("v.name");` will give you selected name only.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution is to set the name of your button to your indexVar (unforunately, aura:id cannot be dynamically set in an aura:iteration). This will allow you to get the index in your controller using: event.getSource().get("v.name"). You can then update the appropriate row in QliList based on that index.